# Android :: Layout Weight and ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout-weight, layout-xml

**PROBLEM**

I want to adjust `ImageView` base on percentage or weight but it can't.

Main Layout consists of 2 Layout inside,they equivalent to 1st row and 2nd row.

In the 1st row there are another 4 layout inside each one have an `ImageView`.

I want these `ImageView` to expand their height and width accordingly

by percentage or weight of its parents width height what should I do?

> Is it possible to let its width scale in weight that I want and let's
>   height
>
> expand relative to its width?

**PICTURE**

[image]

**XML LAYOUT**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/foot_bg">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" 
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_weight="1" 
                    android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_sleepmode" 
                        android:scaleType="matrix" 
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Sleep Mode"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3" 
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                        android:textSize="10sp"/>               
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                          android:layout_width="0dp" 
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="1" 
                          android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
                          android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_temp"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Temperature"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4" 
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                        android:textSize="10sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                          android:layout_width="0dp" 
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:id="@+id/linearLayout5" 
                          android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="70dp" 
                           android:layout_height="70dp" 
                           android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                           android:src="@drawable/ic_tracking"/>

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="Tracking Mode" 
                          android:id="@+id/textView7" 
                          android:textSize="10sp"
                          android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                          android:layout_width="0dp" 
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="1" 
                          android:id="@+id/linearLayout6" 
                          android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="70dp" 
                           android:layout_height="70dp" 
                           android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                           android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"/>

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="Settings" 
                          android:id="@+id/textView8" 
                          android:textSize="10sp"
                          android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="0dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:id="@+id/linearLayout" 
                      android:gravity="center">

            <ToggleButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New ToggleButton"
                    android:id="@+id/tgbPower" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                    android:checked="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Try this to check if the imageview resizes with the weight:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:background="@drawable/foot_bg"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sleepmode" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Sleep Mode"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_temp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Temperature"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tracking" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Tracking Mode"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tgbPower"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="New ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but as you can see they are many children that use weight without weightSum. For example, in the first row with 4 equal width, it's work fine without weightSum. is that really a problem?

Comment: @JongzPuangput Check my edit and see if that's the solution. Basically, you have to have a `weightSum` whenever you want to have various weights for the children.

Comment: Actually, the problem is I want to adjust ImageView with weight. All the layout contain weight that I set is nothings wrong it work fine!

Comment: @JongzPuangput I'm sorry I didn't understood your problem but I think this last edit is the solution to your problem.